# Find and replace in a file

Tags: php, replace

I want to replace certain strings with another one in a **text file** (ex: `\nH` with `,H`). Is there any way to that using PHP?

Comment: [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) is also your friend.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could read the entire file in with [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), perform a [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), and output it back with [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Sample code:

```
<?php

$path_to_file = 'path/to/the/file';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("\nH", ",H", $file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file, $file_contents);

?>
```

Answer (score 14):

There are several [functions to read and write a file](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php).

You can read the file’s content with [`file_get_contents`](http://docs.php.net/file_get_contents), perform the replace with [`str_replace`](http://docs.php.net/str_replace) and put the modified data back with [`file_put_contents`](http://docs.php.net/file_put_contents):

```
file_put_contents($file, str_replace("\nH", "H", file_get_contents($file)));
```

Comment: Now the question really is: is your one-liner faster/more efficient than my three line version? ;-)

Comment: less variables = lower overheads?

Comment: @Paul The advantage is negligible compared to the read, replace, and write operations.

Comment: Yep, @Gumbo, thus I'd rather aim for better readability => better maintenance.

Comment: I was looking for a one liner I could add in my composer json to initialize db settings in my lumen `.env` file (for docker or travis e.t.c). This looks great for situations like that.

Comment: I would rather not store the whole contents of files in variables because that might eat up a lot of memory. In this case, a one-liner might be good, unless you can be sure that the variables will be garbage-collected after using them.

Answer (score 10):

If you're on a Unix machine, you could also use [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) via php's [program execution functions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php).

Thus, you do not have to pipe all of the file's content through php and can use regular expressions. Could be faster.

If you're not into reading manpages, you can find an overview on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed_(Unix)).

Comment: If it's a large file this is actually the route I'd go -- It's probably more efficient than reading the whole thing into a PHP variable and doing a PHP str_replace()

Comment: If you allow php to execute shell commands on a server you open up a security vulnerability. I would only use this if you have knowledge in security both server and PHP. Otherwise you are putting your server at risk.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents()` then `str_replace()` and put back the modified string with `file_put_contents()` (pretty much what Josh said)