# How to convert TXT file contents to URL's using PHP?

Tags: php

I am a newbie to PHP.

I have a test file "names.txt" with different names, for example;

```
Maddox
Magnus
Malcolm
Melvin
Marcus
Mark
Marlon
Martin
Marvin
Matthew
Maurice
Max
Medwin
Melville
Merlin
and so on to 100s
```

I want these names to be in another or in same TXT file as URLs like.

```
<a href="http://example.com/Maddox/something/">Maddox</a></br>
<a href="http://example.com/Magnus/something/">Magnus</a></br>
<a href="http://example.com/Malcolm/something/">Malcolm</a></br>
<a href="http://example.com/Melvin/something/">Melvin</a></br>
<a href="http://example.com/Milburn/something/">Milburn</a></br>
<a href="http://example.com/Marvin/something/">Marvin</a></br>
<a href="http://example.com/Melville/something/">Melville</a></br>
<a href="http://example.com/Montague/something/">Montague</a></br>
and so on to the all names of txt file.
```

I cannot do 100s of them manually, so the question is How can I do this using PHP?

Can you make a PHP code for this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you (even) attempted [to read the manual](http://php.net/file) ?

Comment: Yes, but didn't understand. That's why I have asked.

Comment: It will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438563/find-and-replace-in-a-file

Comment: I have read rules and I had tried but forgot the loop. Got an cue, infect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fp=file("filename");
    foreach($fp as $line)
    {

            echo '<a href="http://example.com/'.$line.'/something/">'.$line.'</a>'; 
            echo "<br>";

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$fp=file("filename");
    foreach($fp as $name)  
    {

        echo '<a href="http://example.com/'.trim($name).'/something/">'.$name.'</a>';   
        echo "<br>";

    }
```

Comment: Link url should contain `name` too. See OP's example.

Comment: There were syntax errors on line  echo '<a href="http://example.com/'.$line.'/something/">'.$line.'</a>';

Comment: I was able to use @Tristup correctly. Your was too good.

Comment: This is not my code echo '<a href="example.com/'.$line.'/something/ @AlanBorder