# PHP code to reflect changes in multiple files

Tags: php

I have a mobile number in something around 50 pages.I wanted to edit the mobile no(not image hardcoded value).Now editing the mobile no in 50 different pages is really hard.Is there any way i can change in one file and it will reflect in all the 50 page.Is there any solution to it.Thank You

Comment: make a variable of that phone no, like $mo_no = '+1954875****', add this file to every single page, and replace static mobile no with this variable. @user7144720

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438563/find-and-replace-in-a-file

Comment: thank you parth but my question is this can be done by copy paste also i dont want to copy paste.

Comment: use Notepad++ editor and open all 50 files and pretty to use find in all opened file and replace  with your new value