# Remove string direct from file without replace the entity file in PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to remove string from file by seeking its position then remove. I dont want to store the entity file in a string than replace. I need to replace it directy on the file, is there any way I could do this?

I have to find the "#" then remove until I find the next.

Example: 
Remove #2 data from myfile.txt

```
  #1|info1|info2|info3|#2|inf11|info12|inf22|#3|inf11|info12|inf22|
```

After remove:

```
  #1|info1|info2|info3|#3|inf11|info12|inf22
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Unless your file uses a fixed width for each item then the only option is to load the entire file into memory, manipulate it and save it back.

Comment: It doesnt.Is it possible to do in other language like C or Java?

Comment: In C you can use `mmap()` to access the file contents as an array in memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438563/find-and-replace-in-a-file)

Comment: @Dom That doesn't show how to do it without reading in and rewriting.

Comment: @Barmar The answer by middus does

Comment: @Dom That answer doesn't even show how to do it, it just describes it in general terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't provide any way to directly manipulate file contents. You have to read into a PHP variable, then write back out to the file.

In C on a POSIX system you can do it using `mmap()`.

```
int fd = open("myfile.txt", O_RDWR);
struct stat stat_buf;
fstat(fd, &stat_buf);
size_t len = stat_buf.st_size;
char *contents = mmap(NULL, len, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
char *num2 = strstr(contents, "#2"); // Find #2
char *num3 = strstr(num2, "#3"); // Find #3 after #2
memmove(num3, num2, len-(num3-contents)); // Shift everything from #3 over
memset(contents + len - (num3 - num2), num3 - num2); // Zero the end of the file
close(fd);
```