# how to replace a string inside files using php

Tags: php

I intend to create a simple codes using php that can replace strings inside the files much like replace function in the notepad and ms word but the difference is it will replace all strings match to the desired  string  to change in all files inside the folder any Idea how to do that?

Comment: Please show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438563/find-and-replace-in-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use useful [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) php function.

**Example**

```
<?php
   $files_in_your_folder = glob('c:\wamp\www\FindReplace\*');
   foreach(glob('c:\wamp\www\FindReplace\*') as $path_to_file) {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
    $file_contents = str_replace("Hello","World",$file_contents);
    file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
   }
?>
```

If You have sub folders in your directory then you can get files with the below code

```
$path = realpath(__DIR__ . '/textfiles/'); // Path to your textfiles 
$files_in_your_folder = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```