# How to explode a text into an array by end of line and then explode it again by colon using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, explode, eol

I'm trying to read a structured log file, explode it by line and after that by colon.

I'm trying in two diferent approaches `fgets` and `file_get_contents`, but in both I'm able to reach only one or the other objective (explode by line **or** by colon).

Here we have the code:

```
<?php

// using fgets
$file = fopen('/var/www/html/PU1PAX.log', 'r');

while (!feof($file)) { // while not end of file
    $content = fgets($file); // get file's content
    $handle = explode(':', $content); // and explode by string

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($handle);
    echo '</pre>';
}
fclose($file);


// using file_get_contents
$file = '/var/www/html/PU1PAX.log';
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$handle = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($handle);
echo '</pre>';
```

The first part of the code prints one array to each line:
    Array
    (
        [0] => START-OF-LOG
        [1] =>  3.0
    )

```
Array
(
    [0] => LOCATION
    [1] =>  DX
)

Array
(
    [0] => CALLSIGN
    [1] =>  PU1PAX
)

Array
(
    [0] => CLUB
    [1] =>   
)

Array
(
    [0] => CONTEST
    [1] =>  CQRJVHF
)
```

The second part prints only one array with all lines ordered:

```
Array
(
    [0] => START-OF-LOG: 3.0
    [1] => LOCATION: DX
    [2] => CALLSIGN: PU1PAX
    [3] => CLUB:  
    [4] => CONTEST: CQRJVHF
)
```

For the first, I would like to find a solution to group all this arrays together, as the content is more or less separated and workable.

For the second, it would be interesting if I could change the array in a way that I could explode it again (this time by colon) to have the first part of the string as the array's keys and the second part as the array's values like the following example:

```
Array
(
    [START-OF-LOG] => 3.0
    [LOCATION] => DX
    [CALLSIGN] => PU1PAX
    [CLUB] =>   
    [CONTEST] => CQRJVHF
)
```

But I'm complete stuck... :-(

Comment: if you know how to explode once , you should be able to explode again . is it ? and why explode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438563/find-and-replace-in-a-file

Answer (score 1):

Use the `file()` function to read the file line-by-line, then you can explode each line and fill your associative array:

```
$lines = file('/var/www/html/PU1PAX.log', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$data = [];
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    @list($key, $value) = explode(':', $line, 2);
    $data[$key] = trim($value);
}

print_r($data);
```

Three things:

- The third argument to `explode()` will take care of situations where the value also contains a ":" character
- I used the much-hated `@` error suppression on `list()` to hide any notices for if a line doesn't contain a ":" character. In that case, `trim($value)` will give you an empty string as value
- That last case is also the reason I included the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag. `trim($value)` would remove it, but if there is no ":" character the newline would be in `$key`, so better to just not have them in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can read character by character `fgetc()`

```
$file=fopen("welcome.txt","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

while ( !feof($file) ) {

   $line = "";
   do {
       $c = fgetc($file);
       $line .= $c;
   } while ( (!feof($file) and $c != PHP_EOL )

  // TODO: process $line (split in columns)

}


fclose($file);
```

P.s.: I didn't test this code. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
//$items = explode(PHP_EOL, $content); in your case
$items = ['START-OF-LOG:3.0','LOCATION:DX','CALLSIGN:PU1PAX','CLUB:','CONTEST:CQRJVHF'];
foreach($items as $item) {
    $line = explode(':', $item); // and explode by string
    $associtativeArray[$line[0]] = $line[1];
    foreach($line as $line_item) {
        $oneDimensionalArray[] = $line_item;
    } 

    $groupedArray[] = $line;

}

print_r($associtativeArray);
print_r($oneDimensionalArray);
print_r($groupedArray);
```

This is the printed result:
    // This is $associtativeArray
    Array
    (
        [START-OF-LOG] => 3.0
        [LOCATION] => DX
        [CALLSIGN] => PU1PAX
        [CLUB] => 
        [CONTEST] => CQRJVHF
    )
    // This is $oneDimensionalArray
    Array
    (
        [0] => START-OF-LOG
        [1] => 3.0
        [2] => LOCATION
        [3] => DX
        [4] => CALLSIGN
        [5] => PU1PAX
        [6] => CLUB
        [7] => 
        [8] => CONTEST
        [9] => CQRJVHF
    )
    // This is $groupedArray
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => START-OF-LOG
                [1] => 3.0
            )

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => LOCATION
            [1] => DX
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => CALLSIGN
            [1] => PU1PAX
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => CLUB
            [1] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => CONTEST
            [1] => CQRJVHF
        )
)
```