# Safely update a file-based setting variable in PHP

Tags: php, regex

For my PHP web app, I have a pre/post -install settings file, say `settings-config.php`.

From this post, we can search and replace exact content in a file using PHP: [Find and replace in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438563/find-and-replace-in-a-file)

Thus, we can replace an exact string. Say...

```
'My foo' --becomes--> 'My bar'
```

...but that is for matching exact characters.

But, for a setting, the web admin may have typed an extra space somewhere, et cetera.

## My situation

I have a settings file. The setting allows the app be installed. When finished, I need to set this to `false`.

| **settings-config.php** :

```php
$allowinstall = true; // change to 'true' to allow install
```

Based on [that Answer (above)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438563/find-and-replace-in-a-file), I created this:

| **search-replace script** :

```php
$conf_file = './settings-config.php';
$conf_contents = file_get_contents($conf_file);
$conf_contents = str_replace("allowinstall = true", "allowinstall = false", $conf_contents);
file_put_contents($conf_file, $conf_contents);
```

But, from human factors, the file might be different

| **settings-config.php*** : (variants)

```php
$allowinstall = true;
$allowinstall =  true;
$allowinstall  = true;
$allowinstall = true ;
$allowinstall  =  true ;
ET_CETERA;
```

...or if the impossible happens (which it often does in programming), it could possibly be...

```php
$allowinstall = truth;
$allowinstall =  tru;
$allowinstall  = truee;
$allowinstall = ture ;
$allowinstall  =  utre ;
ET_CETERA;
```

So, the simple search-replace script (above) isn't good for this.

## What I need

I want every line starting with `$allowinstall =`  to become this:

```php
$allowinstall = false;
```

- The search-replace script should probably use `^` and a regex to make sure that `$allowinstall =`  is the beginning of the content of the line, so a comment won't match (ie `//$allowinstall =`  won't be changed)
- I want to match every instance, so if it happens to be set more than once, all variables will be set to `$allowinstall = false;`
- Something like this:

| **search-replace script** :

```php
$conf_file = './settings-config.php';
$conf_contents = file_get_contents($conf_file);
$conf_contents = str_replace(
  preg_match("^allowinstall".'/any space/'."=".*),
  "allowinstall = false",
  $conf_contents
);
file_put_contents($conf_file, $conf_contents);
```

I don't know how to write that code safely, but I think it would be best if I could. Either way...

What is the "proper" search-replace script, for a situation like this, to update/reset a specific setting in a .php file using PHP?

Comment: IMHO, the only thing "proper" would be not to mess around with search-replace, but to use a data structure instead of single variables - an array, or JSON. Then you read that structure, manipulate it - and use `var_export` or `json_encode` to create a representation of that, that can be written back to the file as a whole.

Comment: @CBroe could you provide a simple answer using an array and var_export, not JSON, so it stays in pure PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this using `var_export`, you start with a simple PHP file containing nothing but your data in form of an array, something like this:

```
<?php

$config = [
    'foo' => 123,
    'bar' => 'abc'
];
```

That file you can include where you need it, then you have your $config variable available to read the values you need.

Then you manipulate the content of your array, f.e. `$config['foo'] = 'xyz';`. If you do a `var_export($config);` now, this will get you

```
array (
  'foo' => 'xyz',
  'bar' => 'abc',
)
```

That is the "old" array syntax, but they are interchangeable, so that doesn't really matter much. What is still missing, is the `<?php` tag, the actual assignment of this array to a variable, and a trailing `;` after it - so these need to be added manually.

```
$new = '<?php $config = ' . var_export($config, true) . ';';
```

var_export with second parameter set to true, because we want it to return the value, not output it directly. This gives you

```
<?php $config = array (
  'foo' => 'xyz',
  'bar' => 'abc',
);
```

- and that is perfectly valid PHP syntax now, and can be written to the file as-is.

Comment: I really like that, much better than search-replace for individual settings.