After using the php function fwrite: extra dots inside the file when viewing online (not after downloaded)
I have a function that create a file using the function fwrite.
I've noticed that after the file is created, if I open the file using the online file manager of my host, I can see an extra dot inside the file. I cannot see this dot when downloading the file on my computer (linux Mint) and viewing it.
This extra dot cause an Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "". When I remove the extra dot online everything works normally.
I have no idea where this extra dot come from and why I cannot see it on my computer.
You can see on the pictures the problem
same file viewed online and on my computer
Here is the code that generate the file:
The file is on a subdomain folder and is generated from the main domain name.
//regenerate the spam list using the updated database
        $path_to_file = '/home/xxxxxxx/domains/xxxxxx.com/public_html/xxxxxxx/banned_words.php';
        $myfile = fopen($path_to_file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt1 = "<?php // The list of not allowed words\n\$not_allowed_words = [\n";
        $txt3 = "];?>";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt1);   
        // Query to fetch stories
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM banned_words ORDER BY id ASC');
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($data as $row) { 
        $banned_word = $row["banned_word"];
        $txt2 = "    '".$banned_word."',\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt2);
        }
        fwrite($myfile, $txt3);

Thank you to anyone with an idea!
I tried to modify the file online (remove the extra dot) and it works
I tried to download the file to modify it but when opening the file on my computer the extra dot does not appear
I tried to modify the function but nothing worked
EDIT:
I have the same problem when generating sitemap files in xml. I tried removing the <? tag to test but the extra character still appears

Can't tell from that screenshot, whether this is actually a "dot" character - or whether perhaps your editor highlights any "non-printable" characters this way ...?

Either way, this is quite "ugly" - trying to dynamically create valid code, is error prone. You should rather be using var_export to get a code representation of the content of a variable - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72305810/1427878. (Or store the data encoded as JSON.)

I don't see any extra character or space when downloading the file on my computer and opening it. I'm not trying to create code but simply to create a list of words to use later with other functions.
Everytime a new  word is added to the database the file containing all the words is rewrited. Other function then use this file (the list of words as a spam filter).
I will have a look to this var_export right now

Also I have the exact same problem when generating sitemaps in xml using urls from a database

"I'm not trying to create code" - what else would you call this then? You are writing something to a file, so that you can include that file elsewhere afterwards, and have it contain valid PHP code that will get parsed right there and then - are you not?

"This extra dot cause an Uncaught Error: Undefined constant" - even more of an indicator that it is not an actual dot then - because a dot in that location, would get you Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ".", expecting "]" (https://3v4l.org/PcinX) That it says undefined constant instead, means PHP is seeing some other character there.

Sorry my knowledges are a bit limited. I also have the same problem when creating xml files without php in it. However it does contain <? that might be the source of the problem as well!

Try and open the downloaded file in a hex editor, or a text editor that can show you the byte code of "unprintable" characters, to figure out what you are actually dealing with here.

It would help if you provided a [mcve], properly formatted. Also, it's unclear what precisely you did or what the "online file manager" means. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Thank you to both of you. Problem resolved by simply retyping the lines with the keyboard !

Problem resolved:
I simply had to delete this line and type it again :
$txt3 = "];?>";
Same problem with the sitemap files generator.
